# Tensorflow logs to stderr and make subprocess fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, keras

I am using Tensorflow and Keras. I have a python script to start the prediction process and I need to start it in a subprocess, so I do it like that:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired
process = Popen(['python', 'start_prediction.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
try:
    output, errors = process.communicate(timeout=60)
except TimeoutExpired:
    process.kill()
    output, errors = process.communicate()
```

I have a logger configured for my application and it's working fine, but there is also a logger used by Tensorflow and it's is what I am having a problem with.

My logger is configured to use a StreamHandler with `sys.stdout` and a FileHandler. When I print out `output` and `errors`, all my log messages are stored in the `output`, there is nothing in `errors`. And this is what I want.

On the other hand, the logger used by Tensorflow does not work as I need it to. Some of the messages are being logged into the `output` (like the prediction process and some warnings) and some of them are being logged into the `errors` stream (other warnings). I am not able to tell if the application has failed or not, because, even if it worked and finished without any errors, I am still getting messages in the `errors` stream.

I tried to redirect all the messages from Tensorflow to the `sys.stdout` doing that:

```
from absl import logging
logging._warn_preinit_stderr = 0
```

and that

```
import logging
import sys
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging
tf_logging.get_logger().handlers = [logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]
```

but it does not help (`logging` imports are in different files, here is a simplified version). In fact, it does not make any difference, at least I did not see any.

Theoretically, I am getting warnings only, so I could suppress all warning messages and keep only errors, but I would rather not do that. There must be a better way to deal with it.

Is there a way to redirect all the Tensorflow output to the `sys.stdout` stream? Or maybe there is another way to not have any non-error messages in the `errors` output?